# Set Expire Date with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a form with inputs and I want on submit button click to take the current time and add 10 hours to update the table cell expdate I have this function but doesn't work

```
<script>
$("#registerButton").click(function() {
    var signintime =$("#scantime").val();
    var id = $("#id").val();
    var expdate = ($("#scantime").val() +36000));
       $.ajax({
            url: "updatescan.php",
            method: "POST",
       data: {signintime:signintime,expdate:expdate,id:id} , 
dataType:"text",   
            success: function(data)
                        {                   
                        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The field with the id #scantime has a real time clock as a value

I have also tried this but it doesn't work with javascript

```
$expdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()+36000);
var expdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()+36000);`
```

i've managed to get current time and insert to db with this

```
var x = new Date();
var x1=x.getFullYear() + "-" + x.getMonth() + "-" + x.getDate();
x1 = x1 + "  " + x.getHours( )+ ":" + x.getMinutes() + ":" + x.getSeconds();
var expdate=x1;
```

but how i add 10 hours to this ?
Thank you

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It doesn't update anything except if I remove the expdate var

Comment: Have you tried checking for errors from the return of the mysql_query() function?

   if (!$retval) {
       die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
   }

Comment: no I am new to php and I don't know how to do that

Comment: i cant see no errors

Comment: how do i put this $expdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()+36000); into a var in the ajax function?

Comment: Unless you want any user to be able to manipulate those values as they like, you should rather do this in the database directly ... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please pay attention that getMonth is month-1

So if you need dates as a string you should use getMonth()+1

```
// php
echo strtotime('now +10 hours');

// js 
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(d.getHours()+10);
```

Comment: it doesn't work i forgot to say that my table for expdate is formatted on datetime format

Comment: found a solution var x = new Date();
var x1=x.getFullYear() + "-" + x.getMonth() + "-" + x.getDate();
x.setHours(x.getHours()+10);
x1 = x1 + "  " + x.getHours()+ ":" + x.getMinutes() + ":" + x.getSeconds();
document.getElementById('scanbartime').value = x1;
var expdate=x1; Thank you

Answer (score 0):

var d = new Date();
d.setHours(10);
The result of d will be:

Wed May 25 2016 15:11:44 GMT+0530 (IST).

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setHours.asp